# Header Menu onPress not working in React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

> onPress ={ ( ) => this.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}

**Is not working**

**error:** ' evaluation_class.navigation.navigate'

[image]

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGzX2.jpg)

onPress ={ ( ) => this.navigation.navigate(' DrawerOpen')} 
Is not warking error : ' evaluation _class.navigation.navigate'
![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLqCy.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please review your question to make it easier for us to understand your code and assist you. [mre] might help you.

Comment: Problem are crate in the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default class Source extends React.Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'India',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: colors.primary,

    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    headerLeft: (
        <Button
          onPress={()=>this.navigation.Drawer.open()} 
          title="Info"
          color="#fff"
        />
      ),
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `onPress ={ ( ) => this.props.navigation.navigate(' DrawerOpen')}`

Comment: I'm try bro.. But props are not working..

Comment: Can you paste more of your code ?

Comment: Check code.. May mistake " static navigationOptions = " what us write here?

Comment: Add navigation but not working..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
export default class Source extends React.Component {

static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
    title: 'India',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: colors.primary,

    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    headerLeft: (
        <Button
          onPress={()=> navigation.navigate(' DrawerOpen')} 
          title="Info"
          color="#fff"
        />
      ),
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes I trying but not solved my solution..

Comment: https://github.com/Awadhesh786/FindJobs/blob/master/src/screen/Home.js please check my code.

Answer (score 2):

In the components which use navigation import `withNavigation`, and at the bottom of your javascript file export your component `withNavigation()`.

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class YourAwesomeComponent from React.Component {

    {your component code}

}
export default withNavigation(YourAwesomeComponent);
```

Then you will be able to use the navigation prop in your component. [This section in the React Navigation documentation explains further](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html)